# JS not executing the code when page loads or refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, translation

So I'm checking this code with a browser in english and it works fine, but when the browser is in pt-br it does not execute $('.translate').on("change", function(), so for the site to execute properly, when using a pt-br browser the user need to change to english and then portuguese to apply the portuguese option. if the user open with a pt-br browser the page should translate to the correspondent language, but it is just chaging the value in select and nothing else, how can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Multiple Languages with Jquery and Json</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="language" class="translate" style="">
    <option value="english">English</option>
    <option value="portuguese">Português</option>
  </select>

  <ul>
    <li class="lang" id="home">Home</li>
    <li class="lang" id="about">About Us</li>
    <li class="lang" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="lang" id="desc">This is my description</p>

  <br>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var arrLang = {
      'english': {
        'home': 'Home',
        'about': 'About Us',
        'contact': 'Contact Us',
        'desc': 'This is my description'
      },
      'portuguese': {
        'home': 'Lar',
        'about': 'Sobre',
        'contact': 'Contato',
        'desc': 'Essa é a descrição'
      }
    };

    // Process translation
    $(function() {
      $('.translate').on("change", function() {
        var lang = $(this).val();

        $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')]);
        });
      });
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    $('.translate').val(userLang == "pt-BR" ? "portuguese" : "english");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is changing the select *before* it assigns the change handler to it. Also: `if (userLang = "pt-BR") {` won't work, you need `==` for comparisons.

Comment: I've done those alterations but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correctly binding the events and setting the value of the dropdown on page load, what you're missing is executing on page load the code that gets executed onchange of the select element.

After you set the value of the select element, you need to manually trigger the change event. I did it here (along with some optimizations)

```
// Process translation
$(function() {
  // grab a reference to the DOM elements
  var $translate = $('.translate');
  var $lang = $('.lang');
  // get the user language
  var userLang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage) == "pt-BR" ? "portuguese" : "english";

  $translate
    // bind the change event
    .on("change", function() {
      var lang = $translate.val();
      $lang.each(function(index, item) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('id');
        $this.text(arrLang[lang][id]);
      });
    })
    // update the value of the language dropdown with the user lang (happens only on page load)
    .val(userLang)
    // trigger the change event so that the callback gets called (happens only on page load)
    .trigger("change");
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jaireina/0rxma3pg/42/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the script is only executed when the input CHANGES.

To fix this, just execute the translation when page loads.

```
$(function() {
  const arrLang = {
    'en': {
      'home': 'Home',
      'about': 'About Us',
      'contact': 'Contact Us',
      'desc': 'This is my description'
    },
    'pt-BR': {
      'home': 'Lar',
      'about': 'Sobre',
      'contact': 'Contato',
      'desc': 'Essa é a descrição'
    }
  }
  const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

  function changeLang(lang) {
    $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('id')]);
    });
  }

  $('.translate').on("change", function() {
    changeLang($(this).val());
  });

  changeLang(userLang);
});
```

Comment: That's duplicate code, you should move it into a function. Plus, moving OP's code that changes the `<select>` to the end of the `$(function() {...})` wrapper will solve the issue *and* make the select show the correct language, which your code doesn't do.

Comment: i don't get what you guys are saying

Comment: @MestreALMO try my example.

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
if (userLang = "pt-BR")
```

But you have to use

```
if (userLang == "pt-BR")
```

To make it a compare

Comment: i've corrected the code with those alterations but it didn't solved the problem at hand